# Lightning component is not defined error while trying to add global action on my lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to add global action on my lightning component I have embedded my component to contact detail lightning page but I am a getting the below error [image]

Please find the code below :

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller="LightningContactController" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.getContactList}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ContactList" type="List"/>
    <lightning:card title="Contacts" >
        <p class="slds-p-horozintal_small">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ContactList}" var="contact">
            <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!contact.Id}" objectApiName="Contact">
                <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
                    <lightning:outputfield fieldName="Name"/>
                    <lightning:outputfield fieldName="Phone"/>
                    <lightning:outputfield fieldName="Email"/>
                </div>
            </lightning:recordViewForm>    
            <br/>
        </aura:iteration>
        </p>
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="New" onclick="{!c.newContact}"/>
        </aura:set>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

................................................................................

Controller.js

```
({
    getContactList : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.fatchcontects(component, event, helper);
    },
    newContact: function(component, event, helper){
        var createContact= $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createContact.setParams({
            'entityApiName':'Contact',
            'deFaultFiedlValues' : {
                'AccountId': componet.get("v.recordId")
            }
        });
        createContact.fire();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your Controller.js

There is a typo. You wrote 'componet' instead of 'component'.

See commented line below:

```
({
    getContactList : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.fatchcontects(component, event, helper);
    },
    newContact: function(component, event, helper){
        var createContact= $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createContact.setParams({
            'entityApiName':'Contact',
               'defaultFieldValues' : {
            // incorrect spelling of parameter.
            // 'deFaultFiedlValues' : {
              //  error in next line
              //  'AccountId': componet.get("v.recordId")
                  'AccountId': component.get("v.recordId")
            }
        });
        createContact.fire();
    }
})
```